# Object extend or deep merge without any overrides (create array of values instead)

Tags: javascript, object

**UPDATE:** finally I got a working solution https://jsfiddle.net/olehmelnyk/oz7ez881/20/ but it looks overcomplicated and requires refactoring;

---

*Working on meta tag parser.*
I'm looking for a plain JavaScript solution to extend/deeply merge two objects, **without any overrides**. Instead of overrides, I want to store original value(s) from the target and the new value from the source as an array.

**Input**
- there will be only one object at a time and, *in this case*, each object will contain only one value at a time, but this value can be at any deep level, like this:

```
let obj1 = {
  og: {
    image: {
      src: 'http://'
    }
  }
};

let obj2 = {
  og: {
    image: {
      width: 640
    }
  }
};

let obj3 = {
  og: {
    image: {
      height: 320
    }
  }
};

let obj4 = {
  og: {
    image: {
      src: 'http://'
    }
  }
};

let obj5 = {
  og: {
    image: {
      src: 'http://'
    }
  }
};

let obj6 = {
  og: {
    image: {
      width: 640
    }
  }
};
```

**Expecting output** should be like this:

```
{
  og: {
    image: [
      {src: '...', width: 640, height: 320},
      {src: '...'},
      {src: '...', width: 640}
    ]
  }
}
```

Possible pseudocode (I'm not sure about the correct algorithm):
- 1. check if something similar to the source already exists in our target
- 1.1 if no - we just add the source to the target
- 1.2 else - we check if we are adding unique source value
- 1.2.1 if yes, we can merge source with the target
- 1.2.2 else we create an array, that contains both original values from the target and new value from the source

Comment: Your output will be different when the objects are merged in a different order. Is that really desirable behaviour? Secondly, what will be the behaviour when the value in one of the input objects is an array?

Comment: @trincot output order is not important, as long as we don't lose any values during the merging process; the only important thing is 1. deep merge of unique values and 2. preserving existing values from overrides - create array and keep collecting unique values; or I'm just too confused with the code and don't understand anything, lol

Comment: I think it will be hard to see from the result whether an array value means it is the result of a merge operation, or just means that one of the objects had that particular array value for a property that the other objects didn't have.

Comment: @trincot have you seen the last update from https://jsfiddle.net/olehmelnyk/oz7ez881/9/ ? - I feel like I'm somewhere close, but I'm stuck with this... I want to create new array value only when source value exists in the current target object

Comment: I have not looked at your code yet, and have not started to work on this, as I first want to be sure that this is useful. Have you understood the issue I am raising with an array being present in one source object?

Comment: @trincot each array value should contain unique values, so we create new array value only to avoid object value overrides - hope this makes sense! Just have a quick look at the latest jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/olehmelnyk/oz7ez881/10 - open console and press 'RUN' button at top left... this should not take too much time to figure out where I'm stuck, at least I hope so

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think we understand each other. What would `{ x: [{y: 2}, { y: 3 }] }` and `{ x: { y: 4 }}` merge into with this logic?

Comment: `x1 = { 
 x: [
   {y: 2}, 
    {y: 3}
  ]
};

x2 = {
 x: {y: 4}
};

merged = { 
 x: [
   {y: 2}, 
    {y: 3},
    {y: 4}
  ]
};
` - hope this makes sence

Comment: That makes sense, but look how ambiguous the result is. By looking at it you could conclude that there was a source object with `x: {y: 3}`, but that is not true. The first source object had an *array* value for `x`, and there is no way you can derive that from the merged object.

Comment: I made a big update at the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/olehmelnyk/oz7ez881/13/ - function objectExtend(target, source) - line 90 is where you should look at - looks like we have everything we might need to do the merge, but my brain is melting right now 

Comment: @OlehMelnyk Your question says the values can occur at any deep level, but your example shows they occur always at `obj.og.image`. Assuming `og` is the tag name, is this structure always consistent? If so you don't need a deep merge, and your code can be much simpler. If not, you might need to provide some more examples.

Comment: @RichChurcher I'm writing a meta tag parser, that will parse <meta> and <rel> tags from html > head section, and later, maybe even from html > body... code at this page merge only open graph tags (og:image), but there will be more - http://ogp.me/ or twitter cards (twitter:title) or something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Holly cow, I made it! 
Now it works as expected, but the code looks overcomplicated so it requires refactoring.

```
function objectExtend(target, source) {
    let flatSource = flattenObject(source); // {og.image.src: 'http://'}

    let flatSourceKey = Object.keys(flatSource)[0]; // og.image.src
    let sourceKeys = flatSourceKey.split('.'); // ['og', 'image', 'src']

    let sourceKey = sourceKeys.slice(-1); // 'src'
    let sourceValue = flatSource[flatSourceKey]; // 'http://'
    let sourceKeyValue = {[sourceKey]: sourceValue}; // {src: 'http://'}
    let sourcePath = sourceKeys.slice(0, -1).join('.'); // og.image

    let flatTarget = flattenObject(target); // target with array of all key-values flattened
    let flatTargetKeys = Object.keys(flatTarget); // array of all flattened target keys
    let targetValue = flatTarget[flatSourceKey]; // target value (if any)

    let targetValueIsArray = Array.isArray(flatTarget[sourcePath]);
    let targetLastValue = targetValue;
    let targetArray;
    if(targetValueIsArray){
        targetArray = flatTarget[sourcePath];
        targetLastValue = targetArray[targetArray.length - 1];
    }

    let targetKey;
    try{
        targetKey = eval(`target.${sourcePath}`);
    }catch(e){/*we don't care*/}

    if(!flatTargetKeys.includes(flatSourceKey) && !targetValueIsArray){
        // because source will contain og.image.width, but after creating an array width will be in array, so og.image.width will look like unique key
        mergeDeep(target, source);
    }else if(flatTargetKeys.includes(flatSourceKey) && !targetValueIsArray){
        // create array with 2 values - current object[key] and source object[key] - we put object with src/width/heigth object
        mergeDeep(target, unflattenObject(sourcePath, [targetKey, sourceKeyValue]));
    }else if(targetValueIsArray){
        targetLastValue.hasOwnProperty(sourceKey)
            ? targetArray.push(sourceKeyValue) // create new array value array.push
            : targetArray.push(Object.assign(targetArray.pop(), sourceKeyValue)); // merge with last array value Object.assign()

        targetKey = targetArray;
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/olehmelnyk/oz7ez881/20/